# XAML ComboBox Error WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

I got a strange error in my XAML. I added a combobox with the designer on WPF.
I gave this combobox 2 items, with the designer. How do I fix this?
The combobox is called: cb_gender. The items: Male and Female

XAML:

```
<Window xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"  x:Class="HotelWPFGoedeVersie.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:HotelWPFGoedeVersie"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid Name="grid_mainwindow" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="321" Margin="0,0,0,-0.2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="518">
            <Grid Name="grid_logo" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="80" Margin="377,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="141">
                <Border BorderThickness="1">
                    <Ellipse Fill="#00FF00" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="79" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="90" Margin="29.2,0.2,0,-0.8"/>
                </Border>
            </Grid>
            <Line Fill="#FF0000" Name="redline" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="4" X1="0" X2="133.6" Y1="70" Y2="70" Margin="385,-29,0,259" />
            <GroupBox x:Name="gb_newreservation" Header="New Reservation" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="263" Margin="19,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="311">
                <Grid Name ="grid_reservation" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="225" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="282">
                    <Label x:Name="lbl_name" Content="Name:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,19,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="0.443,-0.789"/>
                    <TextBox x:Name="tb_name" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="121,23,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Name" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
                    <Label x:Name="lbl_address" Content="Address:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,58,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                    <TextBox x:Name="tb_address" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="22" Margin="121,62,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Address" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
                    <Label x:Name="lbl_room" Content="Room:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,147,0,0"/>
                    <Label x:Name="lbl_date" Content="Date:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,190,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="0.193,-0.07"/>
                    <DatePicker Name="dp_date"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="121,192,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FirstDayOfWeek="Monday" Width="120"/>
                    <ComboBox x:Name="cb_room" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="121,150,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" SelectedIndex="0" IsEditable="True"/>
                    <Label x:Name="lbl_gender" Content="Gender:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,89,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                    <ComboBox x:Name="cb_gender" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="121,92,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" SelectedIndex="0" IsEditable="True">
                        <ComboBoxItem Content="Male" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="118.4" />
                        <ComboBoxItem Content="Female" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="118.4"/>
                    </ComboBox>
                    <DatePicker Name="dp_birthday" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="121,121,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
                    <Label x:Name="lbl_birthday" Content="Day of Birth: " HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,121,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>

                </Grid>

            </GroupBox>
            <Button x:Name="btn_addreservation" Content="Add Reservation" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="19,278,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="103" Height="26" Click="btn_addreservation_Click"/>
            <Button x:Name="btn_deletereservation" Content="Delete Reservation" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="218,278,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="103" Height="26"/>
        </Grid>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

and this is the error:

> Error  CS1061  'MainWindow' does not contain a definition for >'ComboBoxItem_Selected' and no extension method 'ComboBoxItem_Selected' >accepting a first argument of type 'MainWindow' could be found (are you missing >a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: You are not showing the offending code because there is no `ComboBoxItem_Selected` anywhere in your example code.  In general though, if you assign an event handler to an event in XAML then the code behind file has to have a corresponding event handler with that name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First Checkup**

Take a look at property window on your `ComboBoxItem`

> Error CS1061 'MainWindow' does not contain a definition for
>   'ComboBoxItem_Selected' and no extension method 'ComboBoxItem_Selected' >accepting a first argument of type
>   'MainWindow' could be found (are you missing >a using directive or an
>   assembly reference?)

This error happens when there's no binding event. Look for the `ComboBoxItem_Selected` event stub in your `.cs`. Typing event name or double-click on an item of property window automatically generates the event stub with valid parameters, but you might have accidently removed it while coding.

[image]

If there's no method stub in your `.cs` leave it blank like the image above. But if you have the method stub, type the exact event name into the input box.

**Further checkup**

If you have the event method stub in your codebehind and you correctly bound the method to the event, then it's time to **take a close look at the method's parameters.** Similar events in terms of user action can have totally different event argument.

For example.

```
// Click event
private void Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) { ... }

// MouseDown event
private void MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) { ... }

// Users can fire both events above by mouse click.
```

the second parameter is different, way too different. Please make sure you have a valid argument for your event.